# What is the difference between binom.mean() and n*p for a given binomial distribution in Python?

Tags: scipy, statistics

I have created a binomial distribution using Scipy module 
`wend = stats.binom.pmf(np.arange(4),3,.868)`

Now when I compute mean of this distribution using the mean function I get the following result

```
Mean = wend.mean()
```

> 0.25

But if we use the formula of mean for binomial distribution i.e n*p we get 0.86 * 3 i.e

> 2.604

Why is there a difference in the above two ?

Comment: `n*p` is the theoretical mean, `wend.mean()` is the sample mean. Your question is about basic statistics and if off topic on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added up the probabilities of all 4 possible outcomes and divided by 4. That's not the mean of the distribution. That's just 1/4.

The mean of the distribution would have been `(wend * np.arange(4)).sum()`. Multiply the probability of each outcome by the outcome's value and add up the results.